# MVC 4 - routes turn into a query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, query-string

I downloaded the Chinook sample database and I'm trying to build a simple application to teach myself MVC 4 and EF. Chinook is basically a bunch of artists, their albums and tracks in each album. I wanted to create a REST-like URL structure for displaying each artist, their albums and tracks. This is what I was envisioning:

```
Chinook/Artist                              <- List of artists
Chinook/Artist/{id}                         <- Artist details
Chinook/Artist/{id}/Album                   <- List of albums for artist
Chinook/Artist/{id}/Album/{id}              <- Details for an album
Chinook/Artist/{id}/Album/{id}/Track        <- Track listing for album
Chinook/Artist/{id}/Album/{id}/Track/{id}   <- Track details
```

This is what my Route.config looks like:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    name: "chinook_artist",
    url: "Chinook/Artist/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Artist", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "chinook_album",
    url: "Chinook/Artist/{ArtistId}/Album/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Album", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, ArtistId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "chinook_track",
    url: "Chinook/Artist/{ArtistId}/Album/{AlbumId}/Track/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Track", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, ArtistId = UrlParameter.Optional, AlbumId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

My idea was to have `Edit`, `Delete` and `Add` actions as well for all three types of objects, and `Index` would serve as listing.

This works well enough, however this is what my URLs look like:

```
http://localhost:57264/Album/?ArtistId=8&AlbumId=10&TrackId=70
```

In all cases I'm using `Html.ActionLink` with controller, action, etc. To generate links in views. But I can't get my URLs to start with "Chinook" and be "clean" rather than use a query string, like this:

```
http://localhost:57264/Chinook/Artist/8/Album/10/Track/70
```

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Am I going against the grain of how MVC is supposed to work? Are my routes defined incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the last 2 routes

```
Chinook/Artist/{id}/Album/{id}/Track
Chinook/Artist/{id}/Album/{id}/Track/{id}
```

Your route definitions would need to be

```
//Chinook/Artist/{artistid}/Album/{albumid}/Track
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "chinook_track",
  url: "Chinook/Artist/{ArtistId}/Album/{AlbumId}/Track",
  defaults: new { controller = "Track", action = "Index" }
);

//Chinook/Artist/{artistid}/Album/{albumid}/Track/{id}
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "chinook_trackdetails",
  url: "Chinook/Artist/{ArtistId}/Album/{AlbumId}/Track/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Track", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and your controller

```
public class TrackController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index(int ArtistId, int AlbumId)
  {
    ....
  }
  public ActionResult Details(int ArtistId, int AlbumId, int id)
  {
    ....
  }
}
```

and in the view, generate the links as

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Track", new { ArtistId = 5, AlbumId  = 3 }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Track", new { ArtistId = 5, AlbumId = 3, id = 7 }, null)
```

Then if you wanted a route to edit a track in a similar format

```
//Chinook/Artist/{artistid}/Album/{albumid}/Track/{id}/Edit
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "chinook_trackedit",
  url: "Chinook/Artist/{ArtistId}/Album/{AlbumId}/Track/{id}/Edit",
  defaults: new { controller = "Track", action = "Edit"}
);

public ActionResult Edit(int ArtistId, int AlbumId, int id)
{
  ....
}

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Track", new { ArtistId = 5, AlbumId = 3, id = 7 }, null)
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful, thank you very much. I wasn't understanding the relationship between configured routes, the controllers and their parameters. Thank you again!